# Skipping enum casting

Tags: .net, enums

If I have an a dropdownlist bound to an enum, such as below, and I take the selected value and update my database record that is expecting an int, am I going to be thought of as lazy or ignoring the point of having an enum if I don't cast the int to the corresponding enum value first?

I should probably mention that I am working with legacy code and they are not using classes to model each object, they are just updating the record in the db directly from the UI. No need to tell me why this is bad.

```
public enum Schedule
{
        None = 0,
        Hourly = 1,
        Daily = 2,
        Weekly = 3,
        Monthly = 4,
}
```

Comment: this can be easily figured out by testing.

Comment: what? it is conceptual. how do you test that? please re-read my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see this as lazy. The names of an `enum` are for our benefit. The database only cares about its value and that is what you are giving it.

Comment: it is incorrect answer. What matters is DB access API that you use.

Comment: @Andrey You may be right but you're presuming things outside the scope of what was asked. Nothing wrong with that per-se but it doesn't make my answer incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer; depends.

Longer answer; depends on how your current DAOs persist and retrieve enums. NHibernate will, by default, try to persist the ToString() of the enum; it's much more readable in the actual DB than the numeric value, and you have to specifically state that you want it persisted as the number.

ADO.NET will, AFAIK, persist an enum value as its backing number if you pass it in its unadulterated Enum form to a SqlParameter.